# Как определить с высокой точность момент времени максимального уровня шума?

Tags: java

Как определить с высокой точность момент времени максимального уровня шума? 
 Есть wav-запись. Как это можно определить точность момент времени максимального уровня шума и построить график используя java?

Answer (score 1):

По сути WAV файл представляет собой запись амплитуд звука записанных с заданной частотой (sample rate). Обычно запись идет со скоростью 44,1 кГц - то есть 44100 записей в секунду. Человеческое ухо способно воспринимать звуки частотой не более 20 кГц., но при этом скорость восприятия звука что-то около 1 мс. То есть звуки длиной короче 1 миллисекунд не слышны. Поэтому я думаю имеет смысл устроить алгоритм вычисления громкости кусочками по 1 мс. внутри которых амплитуда усредняется по среднему квадрату. В итоге мы получим график громкости (если точнее амплитуд звука) усреденных по скользящему среднему длиной в 1 мс.

Возвращаясь к Java - библиотека и примеры работы с WAV файлами [приведены здесь](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html)

Comment: интересует почему: 

> амплитуда усредняется по среднему квадрату